# Help with freestyle?

Tags: freestyle

Freestyle Xrays through the model no matter what I try, culling seems to be the option that changes this, but does not. I also need to know how to turn off anti aliasing for freestyle lines. Here's the blend file.

Here's my settings and the issue. Blender 2.8.[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iL5sGxE63KLnT1piOzmIM6jV3nY6otto

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'd advise using a more descriptive title that summarizes your issue, to help attract more potential answers

Comment: Welcome. Use must use this link to upload and repost it here. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @LeoNas Firstly, users don't *have* to use blend-exchange, we just prefer it. Secondly, I strongly suggest *not* uploading other people's files to blend-exchange for them. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/should-we-migrate-all-future-blends-not-on-blend-exchange-to-blend-exchange/2279#2279 and https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/827/can-we-re-upload-blends-to-more-permanent-hosts

Comment: Yea I'd appreciate it if you didn't tell me what to do like that. I'm looking for help, not a lecture. I provided plenty of detail as to what my problem is. Do not upload my stuff other places, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of attempts, I figured it out.

In View Layer > Freestyle Line Set > Selection By. You must check "Visibility".
This will enable the Visibility: Visible.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Would you know how to disable any form of anti aliasing on the freestyle lines? It's supposed to be a sharp and pixelated look.

Comment: Sage Light Bwk could help you with that, if he is in this hub.