# Freestyle failure?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

**Below is a render of my object:**

[image]

**I'm using freestyle, but it has these small failures:**

[image]

**The freestyle settings are the defaults.**

I tried to tweak the thickness, position, angle, lighting of the scene. Nothing worked.

**Before posting the question, I looked at some of the same topic right here on this forum, but none of them seem to be the same problem:**

[Help with freestyle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/help-with-freestyle)

[Freestyle flickering problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247642/freestyle-flickering-problem)

[Freestyle : problem with visibility](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/freestyle-problem-with-visibility)

---

**Edit 01:**

**The object has overlapping planes, this is the side view:**

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: @Chris https://drive.google.com/file/d/12JVqJXbs3_iZyMrEHtgora9AFjgemSLl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found 2 solutions to the problem:**

The first was to try to avoid overlapping/intersecting planes as much as possible. I did this using the knife and moving the corner points.

The second (which was the one I used and is much faster) is to change the line style: **Butt -> Round**.

[image]